# PHP Some help understanding this !isset

Tags: php, arrays, key, isset

I am trying to understand this simple code, if someone could explain this one section of code to a beginner. Please bear with me on the simple code and trying to understand this.

I understand what the loops are doing, it's just the `!isset($value[$values])` part that's tripping me up.

Can someone explain to me what's going on with the `!isset` and why it's not set?

Example

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];

$array2 = [4, 5, 6];

$array3 = [7, 8, 9];

$value = [];

foreach ([$array1, $array2, $array3] as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $values) {

        if (!isset($value[$values])) { // Why is this part of the code not set?
         ...
        }

    }
}
```

From my understanding is:

1) `$value[]` Value is an empty array

2) `$value[$values]` You are passing in $values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...) as the $key of the $value array

3) When I var_dump $value[$values] inside of the inner foreach loop I get `Notice: Undefined index:` Why am I getting this? The index should be the numbers right?

4) Lastly, why is `$value[$values]` considered not set?

Comment: It's not set because, well, it's not set. Try stepping through the loops manually. It makes sense when you think about it for a minute.

Comment: Is it because you're assigning `$value` array with a number key `[$values]`, with no value?

Comment: No. You aren't assigning anything to `$value` or its elements. Maybe you're confused because `$value` is an array and `$values` is a scalar, so both are misnamed. Both of the answers you have received are correct. What is it you think `isset` does?

Comment: I think I understand it, $value is the empty array and you're saying that if $value array with the key of $values isn't set then ... this is because you haven't assigned it yet?

Comment: Yes. That's what an undefined index is, so that's why you're getting that notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$value` is an empty array. Therefore, any keys that you are calling within that array will not be set, until you assign a value to that key.

`$value[$values]` is passing `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`, `[ 4, 5, 6 ]`, `[ 7, 8, 9 ]`, so you are calling `$value[1]`, `$value[2]`, etc.

You are getting `undefined index` because the index is undefined. PHP handles this well and issues a `Notice`. Other languages (Java, for example) would issue a `Null Pointer Exception`.

And lastly, because `$value` is an empty array, and that key is not set, `isset()` returns `false`. And `!isset()` would then return `true`, thus the code would execute.

Comment: For the undefined index part - the index cannot be considered defined unless I provide a value along with the key? And your last statement, what do you mean by $values is an empty array? Isn't it just a $variable with the numbers? `foreach ($arr as $values)`

Comment: I'm guessing you meant $value is the empty array on your last statement.

Comment: Thanks for thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When you run this code, $value is empty, so all values that you test are unset, there is no key 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in this array...
So this is why you got the undefined index error...

Comment: Right, I get it now, it's not assigned. Thx.